# How to integration masking phone number for send and receive sms

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to send sms to shipper and shipper replay the SMS to drivers through Twilio.But Shipper don't want to see the courier number.But when the shipper replays the sms the courier able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To do number masking, you need to use a Twilio number to receive the messages and send them on to the other party. [This article explains how you would achieve that](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134067-How-users-can-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-Twilio).

You may also be interested in [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/proxy) which can handle these relationships automatically. It is in preview though, so you need to [request access](https://www.twilio.com/proxy#request-access).

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: There is if you are accepted to the preview. We're not publishing the example code right now because all products still in preview mode are subject to change. If you request access to Proxy you should hear from the product team and they will be able to share the documentation with you.